# How to rollback in Google App Engine NDB after method fails

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a project deployed on Google App Engine....I am facing rollback issue. I want to rollback just like Relational db where we do commit before return or end of method. How do we achieve this in ndb???

Please find below code snippet for clarity

```
class PersonTable(ndb.Model):
    personId = ndb.StringProperty()
    personName = ndb.StringProperty()
    personAddress = ndb.StringProperty()
    personOldReference = ndb.StringProperty()
    scopeReference = ndb.StringProperty()    

class ScopeTable(ndb.Model):
    child = ndb.StringProperty() 
    isPerson = ndb.BooleanProperty()
    parent = ndb.StringProperty()

@endpoints.method(ZGScopeRequest, ZGScopeResponse, name='scope', path='scope', http_method='POST')
def scope(self, request):

    scope = request.scope
    person = request.personName
    list = scope.split('.')
    length = len(list)
    for entry in list:
        newId = GenerateRandomId('SCOPE')   
        child = mobileappmodels.ScopeTable.query(mobileappmodels.ScopeTable.child.IN([entry])).get()
        if child:
            pass
        else:
            index = list.index(entry)
            parent = list[index-1]
            if entry == 'PersonName':
                entry = person
                fetchPerson = mobileappmodels.CommunityTable.gql("""WHERE personName = :1""",entry).fetch()
                update = fetchCommunity[0].key.get()

                update.scopeReference = newId
                update.put()

                save = mobileappmodels.ScopeTable(child=person, isCommunity = True, parent = parent, id=newId)
                save.put()

            elif entry == 'Global':
                save = mobileappmodels.ScopeTable(child=entry, isCommunity = False, parent = '', id=newId)
                save.put()
            else:
                save = mobileappmodels.ScopeTable(child=entry, isCommunity = False, parent = parent, id=newId)
                save.put()

    return ZGScopeResponse(message="Uploaded")
```

Suppose my function fails just before return and after 2nd put, how do I rollback???

Help would be really appreciate as I am new to Google App Engine and NDB

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand. How could it fail after the last put and before the return?

Perhaps you want to run the code in a transaction:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/transactions

You can run it in a transaction, and call ndb.Rollback if needed.

Comment: You are right about, how come it will fail after and before return....technically it won't fail....what i meant was if it fails on second put how to rollback.

Comment: I tried using transaction but it is giving back following error BadRequestError: Only ancestor queries are allowed inside transactions.